# How do I code my meta data to allow my site when googled to display meta description and links

Tags: html, xml, seo, sitemap, meta-tags

How do I structure my meta data or site map in a way that when my site is googled the result can be displayed like the image displayed? What is the code that I would need to use to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Question belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ by the looks of it

Comment: The proper term for those is "[Sitelinks](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=159206#sitelinks)" and you can't control what google wants to do with them. Just make sure you provide a good sitemap file and follow the rest of google's [suggestions](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't.**  Google decides when to do this.  According to my [webmaster tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/):

> **Google has not generated any sitelinks
>   for your site.**
>   Sitelinks are completely automated,
>   and we show them only if we think
>   they'll be useful to the user. If your
>   site's structure doesn't allow our
>   algorithms to find good sitelinks, or
>   we don't think that the sitelinks are
>   relevant to the user's query, we won't
>   show them

Answer (score 1):

Google Create the site link when crawling your web site and finding the strongest pages in your website.

Most of the time its pages that have the best on site parameters like : bounce-rate, time on site, internal link juice and so...

To help Google bot rank this pages as Sitelinks engage the users and ensure that the pages get good internal links[you can check it with Xenu for example]

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the links below the site domain, those are called "site links" and you have to let google decide you deserve them. You might want to add a robots.txt to your site to tell the google bot what you want indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking your domain has to be an authority for the given query (e.g. match domain name) to show sitelinks. Internal linking, URL naming, titles etc. determine sitelink titles

Answer (score 0):

Submit your newest pages to google webmaster here:https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch?hl=en&siteUrl=

You will need to have a Google analytics account and verified ownership of the site.